# Memory issue when working with NSManagedObject in CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, memory-leaks

I am using Core Data in my iPad application to store details. Application provides user an option to backup saved details (in CoreData) in the form of XML to their different cloud services.For this, the application uses following logic to create XML string

1. Fetch all the saved details from ManagedObjectContext.
2. Iterate through all the items in the array, create a formatted XML string from these ManagedObject and its property values.

   ```
    NSString *contentFormat = @"";

    for(FolderItem *folder in contentArray) {
     contentFormat = [contentFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_Title_"
                                                                withString:folder.title];

       contentFormat = [contentFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_Identifier_"
                                                                withString:folder.identifier];



   contentFormat = [contentFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_Shared_"
                                                            withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[folder.shared integerValue]]];

   if ([folder.contentUrl length]) {
       contentFormat = [contentFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_ContentUrl_"
                                                                withString:folder.contentUrl];

   }else {
       contentFormat = [contentFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_ContentUrl_"
                                                                withString:@""];
   }

     }
   ```

But when working with large number (around 15k) of CoreData objects, the application crashes with error "Application terminated due to memory error".

Does anyone have the same experience?

Please share your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your iPhone RAM. some Applications backgroundly run so it will happen.
2. Check your Free Storage in your iPhone.

Refer Below link:

[What is maximum storage capacity of Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220455/what-is-maximum-storage-capacity-of-core-data)

Answer (score 0):

Although in ARC local variables are released once they are out of scope, however, the pointers may still not be released in time especially in a loop. `@autoreleasepool{ }` will ensure they are released at the end of the block.

So try to put the body of the loop in `@autoreleasepool { ... }`; and also put `NSString *contentFormat = @"";` into the `@autoreleasepool` block.