# What is the best location to save videos (multiple) in IOS app locally?

Tags: ios, video, ios8

I am working on IOS app in which i have multiple videos. Which i am showing to the user in list view. I want to add the functionality in which user can download the videos locally and then play it. What is the best location to save those videos (It can be n number of videos). Which folders i can use to save large amount of binary data?

Comment: I'd recommend using core data for that sort of large data.

Comment: @LyndseyScott:: How much data we can save in core data. IS there any limit to it?

Comment: "What is maximum storage capacity of Core Data?": http://stackoverflow.com/a/4220503/2274694

Comment: No, don't store videos in Core Data.

Comment: If you're going to use Core Data (really? _really?_) you still wouldn't store the videos in it. Store the pathnames of the video files; my answer below would still apply: the videos themselves should just ordinary files.

Comment: @matt :: I am not going to use core data...I am just looking for best option to save video data..most probably i am going to use documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to save videos (or images, or any huge blob of binary data) in a database! Just save them to disk. The Application Support folder and the Documents folder are yours to play with. If you don't want them backed up (might be a nice courtesy) then use the Caches folder instead.