# Store huge amount of data with 50 rows/sec speed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have a requirement to fetch data from BLE device. which pumps 50 data per second constantly. And save the same in memory for approximately 1 hours.

So it becomes 60 minutues x 60 seconds x 50 = 180,000 rows.

Is core data capable to handle this much of data or do I need to try any alternative.

Comment: May you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220455/what-is-maximum-storage-capacity-of-core-data

Comment: That might be a huge amount of data, or not so much. How big are the rows?

Comment: each row has 9 double values and one date object